# SQL Syntax Error; Query looks valid and works on other tables

Tags: mysql

I recently added a new table to my database and am getting the following error when I attempt a delete.

DELETE FROM usage WHERE date='2011-07-26';

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'usage where date='2011-07-26'' at line 1

**EDIT: Turns out usage is a reserved word. See this link for reserved words:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html**

Comment: My intention was to both ask and answer the question, as I had the question typed out when I solved it. I later found out that this requires 100 rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
DELETE FROM `usage` WHERE `date` = '2011-07-26';
```

Escape your table names with a back tick (`) to avoid the clashing with reserved words. `USAGE` is a reserved word in this case.